# How to use windows auth with automatic credential from current user in Windows

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, iis, authorization

I have ASP.NET (.Net Framework) app and I want to put it on IIS with windows auth.
But when i run it on IIS, the browser ask me for username and password.
I want to users of windows will get access without this prompt.

I want to auto login for windows users and without changing browser settings.

Comment: This link should help you: [How to enable Windows authentication for a Web site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/authentication/windowsauthentication/#how-to-enable-windows-authentication-for-a-web-site-web-application-or-web-service).

Answer (score 0):

In IIS, select the application you are working on.  On the right hand side there is an icon for Authentication.  Select that and try to enable Windows Authentication and disable Anonymous Authentication.

Comment: I have done this. I enable only windows auth in iis and in my web.config. Never mind what I do, the browser always asks for password. Maybe I must to add something to my web.config, or add some credentials, user, or some script.

Comment: I try to make it done for a week and I know all the simplest tips, like turn on win auth in iss and more like this. In my app it’s dosn’t work.